# css transform: rotate not working properly

Tags: html, css

i got this login/signup form of uiverse (https://uiverse.io/andrew-demchenk0/clever-chipmunk-94) but the body is flipping when clicking on the body itself i want it to flip only when clicking the slider is it achievable

thanks in advance

HTML:

```
        <div class="card-switch">
            <label class="switch">
               <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
               <span class="slider"></span>
               <span class="card-side"></span>
               <div class="flip-card__inner">
                  <div class="flip-card__front">
                     <div class="title">Log in</div>
                     <form action="" class="flip-card__form">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="flip-card__input">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="flip-card__input">
                        <button class="flip-card__btn">Let`s go!</button>
                     </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flip-card__back">
                     <div class="title">Sign up</div>
                     <form action="" class="flip-card__form">
                        <input type="name" placeholder="Name" class="flip-card__input">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="flip-card__input">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="flip-card__input">
                        <button class="flip-card__btn">Confirm!</button>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </label>
        </div>   
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  --input-focus: #2d8cf0;
  --font-color: #fefefe;
  --font-color-sub: #7e7e7e;
  --bg-color: #111;
  --bg-color-alt: #7e7e7e;
  --main-color: #fefefe;
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    /* align-items: center; */
}
/* switch card */
.switch {
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}

.card-side::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Log in';
  left: -70px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.card-side::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Sign up';
  left: 70px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.toggle {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px var(--main-color);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.slider:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 var(--main-color);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.toggle:checked + .slider {
  background-color: var(--input-focus);
}

.toggle:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(30px);
}

.toggle:checked ~ .card-side:before {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .card-side:after {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* card */ 

.flip-card__inner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  perspective: 1000px;
    /* width: 100%;
    height: 100%; */
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .flip-card__inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.toggle:checked ~ .flip-card__front {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.flip-card__front, .flip-card__back {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: var(--bg-color);
  gap: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px var(--main-color);
}

.flip-card__back {
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.title {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.flip-card__input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px var(--main-color);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--font-color);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
}

.flip-card__input::placeholder {
  color: var(--font-color-sub);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.flip-card__input:focus {
  border: 2px solid var(--input-focus);
}

.flip-card__btn:active, .button-confirm:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px var(--main-color);
  transform: translate(3px, 3px);
}

.flip-card__btn {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px var(--main-color);
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--font-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

i tried with chatgpt many things but none worked it either break the flipping or it just doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i can see with your html is to disable click event on your div (and form) in your css  :

See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

```
.flip-card__inner *:not(div){
pointer-events: auto;
}

.flip-card__inner div,.flip-card__inner form{
pointer-events: none;
}
```

```css
.stackoverflow{
/*Fix stackoverflow to match your uiverse.io pen */
height:500px!important;
display:flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
    background: #212121;
}

.wrapper {
  --input-focus: #2d8cf0;
  --font-color: #fefefe;
  --font-color-sub: #7e7e7e;
  --bg-color: #111;
  --bg-color-alt: #7e7e7e;
  --main-color: #fefefe;
  /* display: flex; */
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  /* align-items: center; */
}


/* switch card */

.switch {
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}

.card-side::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Log in';
  left: -70px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.card-side::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Sign up';
  left: 70px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.toggle {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px var(--main-color);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.slider:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 var(--main-color);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.toggle:checked+.slider {
  background-color: var(--input-focus);
}

.toggle:checked+.slider:before {
  transform: translateX(30px);
}

.toggle:checked~.card-side:before {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toggle:checked~.card-side:after {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* card */

.flip-card__inner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* width: 100%;
    height: 100%; */
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.toggle:checked~.flip-card__inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.toggle:checked~.flip-card__front {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.flip-card__front,
.flip-card__back {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: var(--bg-color);
  gap: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px var(--main-color);
}

.flip-card__back {
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.title {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.flip-card__input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px var(--main-color);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--font-color);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
}

.flip-card__input::placeholder {
  color: var(--font-color-sub);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.flip-card__input:focus {
  border: 2px solid var(--input-focus);
}

.flip-card__btn:active,
.button-confirm:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px var(--main-color);
  transform: translate(3px, 3px);
}

.flip-card__btn {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px var(--main-color);
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--font-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flip-card__inner *:not(div) {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.flip-card__inner div,
.flip-card__inner form {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="stackoverflow">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card-switch">
    <label class="switch">
               <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
               <span class="slider"></span>
               <span class="card-side"></span>
               <div class="flip-card__inner">
                  <div class="flip-card__front">
                     <div class="title">Log in</div>
                     <form action="" class="flip-card__form">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="flip-card__input">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="flip-card__input">
                        <button class="flip-card__btn">Let`s go!</button>
                     </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flip-card__back">
                     <div class="title">Sign up</div>
                     <form action="" class="flip-card__form">
                        <input type="name" placeholder="Name" class="flip-card__input">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="flip-card__input">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="flip-card__input">
                        <button class="flip-card__btn">Confirm!</button>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```